# AWS/Serverless Unknown error shows up when trying to reach my lambda

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm currently working on a nodejs lambda API using serverless. Once it's deployed and when I try to reach my API endpoints, the server is returning an internal error, and CloudWatch is not giving me a lot of informations except this output:

```
{
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/sbx_user1051/.serverlessrc.2618284497'",
"code": "ENOENT",
"errno": -2,
"syscall": "open",
"path": "/home/sbx_user1051/.serverlessrc.2618284497",
"stack": [
    "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/sbx_user1051/.serverlessrc.2618284497'",
    "    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)",
    "    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/var/task/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:212:13)",
    "    at createConfig (/var/task/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/config/index.js:38:19)",
    "    at getConfig (/var/task/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/config/index.js:52:5)",
    "    at Object.get (/var/task/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/config/index.js:99:18)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/isTrackingDisabled.js:5:75)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/tracking.js:11:28)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)"
]
```

After an afternoon of search, I couldn't find the beginning of an answer.

I can provide you informations on my sls configuration or else if needed, thanks to anyone that can help me from here.

Comment: How did you deploy this function to AWS? Did you run `sls deploy`? Or some other way?

Comment: Yes I deploy it with `sls deploy [+OPTIONS]`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `os.homedir()` in a framework logic resolves to not existing directory (`/home/sbx_user1051` doesn't exist), at least it's when this error can happen.

Can it be case on your side? What is your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are not some modules that you try to use in the default lambda environment. And you need to create a separate layer with those modules.

Comment: Thank for the answer but what do you mean by "modules are missing in the default lambda environment" ? I've some projects using the same structure as this one but I've never experienced this issue.

When I do search about this issue, turns out It can be an npm/sls related issue and not necessarily an AWS one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your handle value on the lambda to make sure it is consistent with your entry function.

[image]